# Showing a joint function is a pdf and joint MGF

Tags: density-function, moment-generating-function

[image]

[image]

I have these two problems that are on a previous final for my class.

for Number 3, I know that the double integral from 0 to infinity of f(x+y)/x+y dxdy has to equal 1.
But I have no idea how to tackle that f(x+y).

For Number 4 I tried to do something along the lines of doing a change of variables and using
 $$\ E(e^{ua + vb}) = E(e^{a(X+Y)} + e^{b(X^2 +Y^2)})
$$
Then I expanded that out and put it in terms of U, V. It doesn't seem like it's working out for me though, I also tried completing the square, which I think is the right thing to do.

Comment: Hint:  The function $f(x+y)/(x+y)$ has the same value $f(z)/z$ along the straight line segment with endpoints $(z,0)$ and $(0,z)$. This suggests that a change of variables $u=x+y$, $v=x-y$ will work nicely.

Comment: Please add the `[self-study]` tag & read its wiki.

Answer (score 1):

3. Let $f(\cdot)$ denote the density function of a continuous positive random variable
   and define $$g(x,y) = \begin{cases}\displaystyle \frac{f(x+y)}{x+y}, & x, y > 0,\\
   0, & \text{otherwise.}\end{cases}$$
   We are asked to prove that $g(x,y)$ is the density function of two jointly
   continuous positive random variables. It is obvious that $g(x,y) \geq 0$ for all
   $x$ and $y$, and so all that remains to be proven is that the volume $V$ of the
   (prismatic) solid whose base is the first quadrant and whose upper surface is
   $g(x,y)$ is equal to $1$.  The standard way of doing this is via a two-dimensional
   or iterated integral:
   $$ V = \int_0^\infty \left[\int_0^\infty g(x,y)\,\mathrm dx \right ]\,\mathrm dy
   \tag{1}$$
   which can be thought of as finding the volume of a thin slice of the solid
   between $y$ and $y+\Delta y$. The area of the cross-section is
   $\int_0^\infty g(x,y)\,\mathrm dx$ (which is the inner integral in $(1)$), the thickness of the slice is $\Delta y$, and when
   we pass from the Riemann sum to the integral, we get the outer integral in 
   $(1)$.
   In *this* instance, since $g(x,y)$ has *constant value* $\frac{f(z)}{z}$
   on the straight-line segment with endpoints $(0,z)$ and $(z,0)$, we can instead
   consider a *diagonal* slice whose cross-section is a *rectangle* of
   base length $z\sqrt{2}$ and height $\frac{f(z)}{z}$ so that the area of
   the cross-section is just $\sqrt{2}f(z)$. But, the *thickness* of the slice
   (which lies between the straight-line segment with endpoints $(0,z)$ and $(z,0)$
   and the straight-line segment with endpoints $(0,z+\Delta z)$ and 
   $(z+\Delta z,0)$) is just $\frac{\Delta z}{\sqrt{2}}$ (think about it!)
   and so the volume of the slice is just $f(z)\Delta z$. Adding up the thickness
   of all such slices and passing to the limit, we find that the volume $V$ is
   just
   $$V = \int_0^\infty f(z)\,\mathrm dz $$
   and so we get that $V = 1$ since we have been told that $f(\cdot)$ is a density with support $(0,\infty).\\$
   More formally, as I suggested in a comment,
   all this can be done via a change of variables corresponding
   to a rotation of axes by $\pi/4$, but I can never remember the Jacobian
   stuff, especially on exams.

---

4. Your expression 
   $E\left[e^{Ua + Vb}\right] = E\left[e^{a(X+Y)} + e^{b(X^2 +Y^2)}\right]$
   is incorrect; you should get $E\left[e^{a(X+Y)+ b(X^2 +Y^2)}\right]$.
   Then, when you set up the corresponding integral, you will need to use
   a technique called *completing the square*; the kind of stuff that
   you do when you add and subtract $b^2$ to convert
   $$x^2+2bx + c = x^2 + 2bx + b^2 - b^2 + c
   = (x+b)^2 - b^2 + c$$